# Why does my glassfish localhost redirects to the public ip address?

Tags: deployment, configuration, glassfish, ip-address, local

So there's a deployed web app on a glassfish server. The application has a http listener correctly configured, its ip address (x.x.x.x:8080) is accessible from any external network.
The problem comes when trying to access the same app on a local network, whether it is with the localhost or the server's ip address.
The first page is a login page and that loads up correctly (127.0.0.1:8080/login) or (192.y.y.y:8080/login), but after clicking on the login button, the application returns that x.x.x.x is taking too long too respond.

After checking the app's code there doesn't seem to be any hard-coded address, so I suppose the problem must be in the server configuration.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: And what happens if you connect on the local network using x.x.x.x:8080/login? Does that work?

Comment: No, the public domain is not accesible from the local network and its not supposed to be as far as I understand